Magento 2.4.4p4 EE - GTM Session Regeneration on Every Page Load
I'm encountering a discrepancy between user/session activity and transaction count in Google Analytics (GA) for a Magento 2.4.4p4 Enterprise Edition project. The culprit seems to be frequent GTM session regeneration triggered by the GTM tags script for the datalayer.
Here's a breakdown of the situation:

GTM Tag Implementation:


Installed GTM tags with the script placed in the source code (app/design).
Observed a significant discrepancy between user/session and transaction data in GA.


Troubleshooting Steps:
Script Initialization Location:




Initially placed the GTM tags script in the source code (app/design).

Attempted to move the script initialization from app/design to app/code through default.xml to potentially avoid conflicts.

Unfortunately, the session regeneration issue persisted.
GTM Code Review and Fixes:


Inspected the GTM code for potential issues like undefined IDs or wishlist functionality.

Implemented fixes within the code to address these identified problems (e.g., defining missing IDs, resolving wishlist issues).
Fresh Magento Installation Test:


Installed a clean Magento 2.4.4p4 EE instance locally.

Replicated the GTM tag implementation on the fresh installation.

Observed that the session regeneration problem still occurs, suggesting a potential issue within Magento core itself.



Code Snippet:

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->


Requirement and Observation:


GTM requires the script at the head of every page for proper loading.
Script presence leads to session regeneration on every page change.
Script absence prevents datalayer push to GTM.

Question:
I don't fully grasp how this script interacts with Magento's session regeneration mechanism. However, it appears to be the only factor I can manipulate.
To further investigate:

I replicated the issue on a fresh Magento 2.4.4p4 EE installation.
This suggests a potential Magento or GTM script-related issue, but I'm unsure of the root cause.

Request:
I'd greatly appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this session regeneration problem and ensure accurate data collection in GA.

Hi, this issue has been fixed, apparently it is caused by the GTM tags from google side
